# concatenate files in a pairwise manner

Tags: bash, shell, concatenation, zsh

I would like to concatenate existing .txt files within a directory in a pairwise manner -creating all possible combinations of the original files. Im not sure how to go about using `bash` or `zsh` `shell scripting`, not really my strong suit. I guess one would need to output new files to another directory, preventing an exponential increase of combinations.

Below is a dummy example. In reality I have more files.

```
echo 'A' > A.txt
echo 'B' > B.txt
echo 'C' > C.txt
```

where `A + B` is the same as `B + A` and the order has no importance.

Desired output:

```
>ls
AB.txt AC.txt BC.txt

>head AB.txt
# A
# B
>head AC.txt
# A
# C
>head BC.txt
# B
# C
```

The below is an attempt (at something...)

```
#!/bin/zsh

counter = 1
for i in *.txt; do
    cat $i $counter $i
done
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the files already? Or do you want them created?

Comment: I have them created already.

Comment: Your examples do not match your questions: You say, you want to concatenate your files, but your sample output looks like you want to merge the lines of the input files together. Which is it and where does the `# ` come from? Furthermore it seems that for your purposes `A.txt + B.txt` is the same as `B.txt + A.txt`. Is this assumption correct? If so, is it important which file comes first?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the question accordingly. Yes, `A + B` is the same `B + A` and the order is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh` you can do the following:

```
filelist=(*.txt)
for file1 in $filelist; do
    filelist=(${filelist:#$file1})
    for file2 in $filelist; do
        cat "$file1" "$file2" > "${file1%.txt}$file2"
    done
done
```

**Explanation**:

Store list of `*.txt` in `filelist`, the surrounding parentheses make it an array:

```
filelist=(*.txt)
```

Iterate over all elements in `filelist` for `file1`:

```
for file1 in $filelist; do
```

Remove `file1` from `filelist`:

```
    filelist=(${filelist:#$file1})
```

Iterate over the remaining elements in `filelist` for `file2`

```
    for file2 in $filelist; do
```

Concatenate `file1` and `file2`. Save into new file with combined name (removing `.txt` from the end of the first file name.)

```
        cat "$file1" "$file2" > "${file1%.txt}$file2"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by using a simple nested loop

```
for a in *; do
  for b in *; do
     cat "$a" "$b" > "${a%.txt}$b"
  done
done
```

You can try too a recursice approach

```
#!/bin/bash -x

if [ $# -lt 5   ]; then
   for i in *.txt; do
      $0 $* $i;
   done;
else
  name=""

  for i ; do
    name=$name${i%.txt}
  done
  cat $* >> $name.txt
fi;
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. If I have e.g. 100 files in the directory, I guess I would need to have like 99 nested loops? I clarified my question.

Comment: If you have 100 files in a directory and you want to combine it ordered in every possible position you will need more disk than Google have

Comment: I see your point. But is it possible to achieve the same output but without having to do nested loops?

Comment: You can create a function and make recursive calls, controlling the depth of the algorythm. 100 files cand be ordered from 100! manners

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, `for i in $(echo $*) ;` can be simplified to `for i ;` because `for` uses the positional parameters if nothing is supplied.

Comment: Thanks, @joeytwiddle . You didn't misunderstood anything, so I've commited your change

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in Python. Put this in `/usr/local/bin/pairwise` with executable permissions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import combinations as combo
import errno
import sys

data = sys.stdin.readlines()

for pair in combo(data, 2):
    try:
        print pair[0].rstrip('\n'), pair[1].rstrip('\n')
    except OSError as exc:
        if exc.errno = errno.EPIPE:
            pass
        raise
```

Then try this:

`seq 4 | pairwise`

Resulting in:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

Or try this:

```
for x in a b c d e; do echo $x; done | pairwise
```

Resulting in:

```
a b
a c
a d
a e
b c
b d
b e
c d
c e
d e
```